# Google drive api search query with partial match on property value

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to use Google drive api through files().list().setQ(q).execute() where I have

q = "properties has { key='Code' and value contains 'abc' and visibility='PUBLIC' }"

Is there no option to use "contains" operator for value? I want to do partial matching on the value.

I get the following error (used in java).

com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request { "code" : 400, "errors" : [ { "domain" : "global", "location" : "q", "locationType" : "parameter", "message" : "Invalid Value", "reason" : "invalid" } ], "message" : "Invalid Value" }

The exact same query works if I replace "contains" with "=" when there is an exact match.